# Robolectric - how to mock com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem?

Tags: android, mocking, actionbarsherlock, robolectric

I'm trying to write tests with *Robolectric* for an App that uses *SherlockActionBar*.
I need to test if the applications does the right thing if an `MenuItem` is selected, but the Robolectric lib gives only mocks for `android.view.MenuItem` while the app uses the method `onOptionItemSelected(com.actiombarsherlock.view.MenuItem)`.

So my questions are:

- May be there is a potability to mock the `com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem`?
- Or a workaround or something?

**Thanks in advance...**

Comment: Why do you need specific MenuItem implementation?

Comment: You can't use SherlockActionBar and try to implement `onOptionItemSelected()` with android.view.MenuItem =)

Comment: :) I meant for tests. You could use TestMenuItem or Mockito to mock classes as well. But why do you required actionbarcherlock MenuItem in method specification? Do you use specific API from it?

Comment: Unfortunately, when I test the class with `TestMenuItem` that is provided by `Robolectric` it calls another method `onOptionItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)` which is not used by my class (An by the way, it can't be used). That's why I started to search for an workaround... For a reason, I don't know, the author of `SherlockActionBar` uses it's own interface for `MenuItem's`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So... becous there is no *more elegant* way to mock the `com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem` I did this:

- Made my own class that implements `com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem`
- Added a int field for itemId in my mock class.
- Other methods from the `MenuItem` interface are left blank (may be I'll use them in other tests)

As a result i got this kind of test:

```
com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item = new TestSherlockMenuItem(R.id.some_action);

activity.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

ShadowActivity shadowActivity = Robolectric.shadowOf(activity);
Intent startedIntent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivity();
assertNotNull(startedIntent);

ShadowIntent shadowIntent = Robolectric.shadowOf(startedIntent);
assertThat(shadowIntent.getComponent().getClassName(),
                equalTo(NextActivity.class.getName()));
```

By the way, thanks to **Eugen Martynov** for trying to understand my problem:)

Comment: Use Mockito to save time with implementation. You need two lines of code: 'com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item = mock(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem);' and 'when(item.getId()).thenReturn(R.id.some_action);'